# Adding iPad Pro screenshots to iTunesConnect for all localisations

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, screenshot

I have several localisations in itunesConnect, primarily to describe the app in other languages, but essentially the graphics for screenshots are the same. As it stands, I need to upload the same iPad Pro screenshot for each localisation separately. Alot of duplication.

Is there anyone who's figured out a way to add a screenshot to make it go in for all localisations on 1 upload to make this process more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you look at [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools). In particular `snapshot` which automates grabbing and localizing screenshots, and `deliver` which automates submission. It was updated to support iPad Pro a few weeks ago.